# independent simultaneous input

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port

In my python code I want to read data from a serial port as well as take input from the user through a keyboard.the data from the serial port and the keyboard can come at any time and are independent of each other.I started with making two threads for the two inputs.

```
import thread

def serialread():
 while 1:
  while(is.Waiting>0)
   out+=ser.read()
  print out
# now do something with the input 'out'

def keyboard():
 while 1:
  print(raw_input("Enter a Command"))
#now do something with the keyboard input

thread.start_new_thread(serialread,())
thread.start_new_thread(keyboard, ())
```

When i run the above code the terminal waits for both the keyboard input as well as the serial read before going into the next iteration, but i want that when there is a serial read then only that thread should work and whenever there is a keyboard inp then the respective thread should work, it should not wait for both the inputs and then only got to the next iteration.

is this possible??should i use the threading module??

Comment: The `thread` module is a *low-level* module which you shouldn't use. In python3 it was even renamed to `_thread` (note that, in python, there is a convention of using `_name_starting_with_underscore` to denote *private* attributes/objects). However I don't understand your question. Your code should work just fine. Can you show the inputs you are giving and explain exactly how the program behaves(and what's your expected behavour)?

Comment: sorry for not being clear.

for ex.

if there is a serial input "start action 1"
and there is no key board input, then the program should start the "action 1" without waiting for a keyboard input..
but in the above code until and unless there is a keyboard input , the action 1 will also not start.i mean i want the two inputs to run independent from each other and the processing from the respective inputs should also be independent.
hope i was clear this time.

Comment: should i use multiprocessing for this..??